# Ruby on Rails. Running app for the first time. Keep running into same error in browser. PagesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Summary:

I've installed rails, all editors, and other components to start working. 
created a new app and running server from WindowsPowerShell cmd window.

first I coded:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
end
```

then I coded:

```html
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end

    def about
    end
end
```

finally I made two files

app/views/pages
   <>about.html.erb
   <>home.html.erb

When I refresh browser local3000 and local3000/about i get

PagesController#home is missing a template for request formats: text/html

I've tried starting from scratch with a new app, running it from gitbash, also running it from cmd line.

I'm working on Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is finding your controller correctly, but it doesn't have a template to respond with.

You need to create the corresponding view file: `app/views/pages/home.html.erb`, `app/views/pages/home.html.erb`

For each public-facing action in your controller you need to specify a view. Rails assumes that these views match the controller class name, downcased, without the `Controller` suffix, named by their action — in `def home`, `home` is the action.

You can explicitly respond inside the action,

```
def home
  render html: "Home!"
end
```

Perhaps you want to respond with JSON,

```
def home
  render json: { hello: "Jacob" }
end
```

Or maybe get fancy, and use the `params` in your inline response:

`http://localhost:3000/?name=Jacob`

```
def home
  render json: { name: params[:name] }
end
```

See the guides for more info: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Josh Brody thank you for the quick reply! I have created those files, still getting the same error.         I did app/views/pages/about.html.erb as well as      app/views/pages/home.html.erb

Comment: could you throw your code on github for a quick peak?

Comment: booted fine for me. try restarting your rails server? sounds like a weird Windows thing.

Comment: Any advice on steps forward?